# Is it possible to have two possible names for the same message part in a WSDL file?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, wsdl2java, wsdl.exe

Hello dear wsdl users,

I'd like to know if there is a way to have two possible names for the same message part in a wsdl file :

I currently have the following .wsdl file :

```
<message name="MyMessage">
    <part name="MyPart1" type="MyType1"/>
    <part name="originalExtension" type="Extension"/>
</message>
<portType name="MyPort">
    <operation name="MyOperation">
        <input message="XX:MyMessage"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="XX" type="XX">
    [...]
</binding>
```

Clients used to send notifications to this service with a `<part>` element named "**originalExtension**" :

```
<MyOperation>
    <MyPart1></MyPart1>
    <originalExtension></originalExtension>
</MyOperation>
```

But this behavior has since changed and now clients can send new `<part>` elements named "**newExtension**" :

```
<MyOperation>
    <MyPart1></MyPart1>
    <newExtension></newExtension>
</MyOperation>
```

The current WSDL file does not handle these new `<part>` elements and crashes ; is it possible to modify either the WSDL or the parent XSD file, to handle both possible names, such as :

```
<message name="MyMessage">
    <part name="MyPart1" type="MyType1"/>
    <part name="originalExtension|newExtension" type="Extension"/>
</message>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)